# Validate date in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)

One of my columns have date type. How do I validate date by only accepting future dates?

Thanks.

Comment: Some more code please.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a custom validator according to this [tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/322_validation), in your case it should be like this:

1. Add 'ui-grid-validate' directive to ui-grid tag in HTML

   ```
   <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-validate        
   class="grid"></div>
   ```
2. Inject 'uiGridValidateService' service in the controller .js

   ```
   app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'uiGridValidateService', function ($scope, uiGridValidateService)
   ```
3. Declare column definition of the date like this:

   ```
   $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
      //other columns
      { name: 'myDate', displayName: 'my date',  
      validators: {
            required: true, compareDateNow: ''
      }, 
      cellTemplate: 'ui-grid/cellTitleValidator' }
   ];
   ```
4. Implement your validate methode which comares between the cell value and current date:

   ```
   uiGridValidateService.setValidator('compareDateNow', 
     function (argument){
       return function (oldValue, newValue, rowEntity, colDef) {
           if (!newValue) {
               return true;
           } else {
               return (newValue >= Date.now());
           }
       };
     },
     function (argument) {
       return 'error message';
     }
   );
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using the editable module?  The standard date editor looks to only accept valid dates.

If you want something more than this, you would define a new directive for a special date editor, and include validation within that directive.  When creating a new directive you want to make sure you provide the mandatory EDIT events, refer the tutorial for more information: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable